# Adding a CP bar to the front end for logged-in members

Tags: control-panel

is there a way to add the top horizontal CP bar that appears in the back end to the front end as well, for logged in members to see? WordPress and Drupal both have this, trying to figure out how to do it in EE. The idea is to provide a shortcut the the backend and to the Content menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this add-on, Missing Link:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/missing-link